# Find the smallest sum of the absolute differences of k pairs of an array

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given n integers and a number k (k<=n/2). Find the smallest sum of the absolute differences of k pairs of an array.

Example 1:

> **Input:**
>
> 5 2
>
> 2 5 3 3 6
>
> **Output:**
>
> 1

Explain: |3 - 3| + |6 - 5| = 1

Example 2:

> **Input:**
>
> 6 3
>
> 868 504 178 490 361 603
>
> **Output:**
>
> 462

Explain: |868 - 603| + |504 - 490| + |178 - 361| = 462

I had tried brute force but can't pass other testcases with large number. I think this could be solved with dynamic programming but don't know how to do it.

This is my code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct PAIR
{
    long long a,b,c;
};

bool compare(PAIR fi,PAIR se)
{
    return fi.c<se.c;
}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    cout.tie(0);
    long long n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    long long a[n+1];
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    long long f[n+1][n+1];
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<=n;j++)
        {
            f[i][j]=abs(a[i]-a[j]);
        }
    }
    vector<PAIR>t;
    long long index=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<=n;j++)
        {
            if(i!=j)
            {
                t.push_back(PAIR());
                t[index].a=i;
                t[index].b=j;
                t[index].c=f[i][j];
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
    sort(t.begin(),t.end(),compare);
    long long res=1e9;
    for(int i=0;i<t.size();i++)
    {
        long long temp=t[i].c,l=1;
        map<long long,long long>cnt;
        cnt[t[i].b]++;
        cnt[t[i].a]++;
        for(int j=0;j<t.size();j++)
        {
            if(l==k) break;
            if(cnt[t[j].a]==0&&cnt[t[j].b]==0)
            {
                temp+=t[j].c;
                cnt[t[j].a]++;
                cnt[t[j].b]++;
                l++;
            }
        }
        res=min(res,temp);
    }
    cout<<res;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the constraints of `N` and `K`?

Comment: n <= 1000 and k<=500

Comment: Notice - yours is c++ code, do you miss the tag?  Also, can you share the original source link?

Comment: [Why is "Can anyone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `O(N * K)` solution would pass, then we can solve the problem using `dynamic programming`.

Let `dp[i][j]` be the minimun cost to use the first sorted `i` numbers, using `j` pairs. We can write:

```
dp[0][j] = INT_MAX; // for each j between 0 and K.
dp[i][j] = std::min(dp[i - 1][j], a[i] - a[i - 1] + dp[i - 2][j - 1]); // for each j between 0 and i / 2
```

Comment: I think the initialization is wrong, shouldn't it be `dp[i][0] = 0;` for each i ? Other than that, that's a nice solution.